# How to get date time from PointPair in X axis using ZedGraph in C#?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I able to make the graph X axis to display in DateTime format, but I couldn't to get date time when my mouse point to the curve item, the PointPair only return data in double. How do I get the date ?

```
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = new XDate(DateTime.Now);  // We want to use time from now
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = new XDate(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));  // to 5 minutes per default
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Second;         // set the minimum x unit to time/seconds
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;         // set the maximum x unit to time/minutes
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "T";
```

Below is the function

```
private string MyPointValueHandler(ZedGraphControl control, GraphPane pane, CurveItem curve, int iPt)
{
        // Get the PointPair that is under the mouse
        PointPair pt = curve[iPt];

        if( curve.Label.Text == "Temperature" )
            return curve.Label.Text + " is " + pt.Y.ToString("f2") + " ºC at " + pt.X.ToString("f2");
        else
            return curve.Label.Text + " is " + pt.Y.ToString("f2") + " % at " + pt.X.ToString("f2");

}
```

I want to the result like eg: Temperature is 23ºC at 4:20:12 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    PointPair pt = curve[iPt];
    XDate the_date = new XDate(pt.X);

    if( curve.Label.Text == "Temperature" )
        return curve.Label.Text + " is " + pt.Y.ToString("f2") + " ºC at " + the_date.DateTime;
    else
        return curve.Label.Text + " is " + pt.Y.ToString("f2") + " % at " + the_date.DateTime;
```